# How can I declare a class template pointer in another class（in the same hpp file）?

Tags: c++, class, pointers, templates

I have defined a class template `RBT_COMMON_PACKAGE` and I want to create a member variable of type `RBT_COMMON_PACKAGE*` in another class.

I get the error:

> error2955: RBT_COMMON_PACKAGE': use of class template requires template argument list

Here is the code:

```
template< class T , int N>
class RBT_COMMON_PACKAGE; // Forward definition
{
public:
    COORDINATES start;      
    COORDINATES target;     
    RBT_CAR      world_start;   
    RBT_CAR      world_target;  
    //RBT_CAR_PNT        via;       
    int                  prep;      
    int                  type;      
}
class PROTECT
{
private:
    RBT_COMMON_PACKAGE *p0;
    RBT_COMMON_PACKAGE *p1;
}
```

Comment: You need to know the template parameters to make a variable of a template class.  If p0 and p1 will have the same template parameters then you can make PROTECT take template parameters too.  If not you can supply them individually.  What template parameters would p0 and p1 take?

Comment: p0 and p1 will have the same template parameters，and I think the class PROTECT should be made as template class,such as ,template< typename T , int N> class PROTECT , am I right?

Comment: That is what I would do.  Something like this: https://onlinegdb.com/4jUE4x1Su

Comment: This is right,thanks very much